# Libraries for compressing and saving sound in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, compression, media, recording

I wish to export a sound recording on iOS from an app into some kind of format that's suitable to be sent over email. Since this leaves a compressed format this leaves out uncompressed wav, and leaves a choice of mp3, ogg, m4a..

What readily available libraries (or even APIs) are available in iOS to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation will do the job for you.  In particular, you should look at AVExportSession, which is explicity written for encoding pcm into mp3 or m4a.  Sorry, no ogg here.  This stuff was available since iOS4.